# Ctools custom relationship plugin (context)

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I am trying to create a custom ctools relationship plugin

1. Create a custom context based on another context
2. With the data from the required context I want to provide some tokens

When I create a custom context relationship using the example in **ctools_plugin_example/relationships/relcontext_from_simplecontext.inc**
the context gets created but there is only the main parent keyword "**Keyword: %relcontext_2**" without any tokens to use.

In the simplecontext example tokens are created by 
**'convert list' => 'simplecontext_convert_list'
'convert' => 'simplecontext_convert'.**

However in the relationship example the comments simply says:

**// Create the new context from some element of the parent context.
// In this case, we'll pass in the whole context so it can be used to
// create the relcontext.**

So how does this work ?

I would like to add a required context of a taxonomy term and then be provided with tokens 
Adding the 'convert list' functions to the relationship example doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php

 /**
    * @file
    *
    * Sample relationship plugin.
    *
    * We take a simplecontext, look in it for what we need to make a relcontext,    and make it.
    * In the real world, this might be getting a taxonomy id from a node, for example.
    */

    /**
    * Plugins are described by creating a $plugin array which will be used
    * by the system that includes this file.
    */
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t("Custom context"),
  'keyword' => 'multi_term',
  'description' => t('Adds a relcontext from existing term.'),
  'required context' => new ctools_context_required(t('Taxonomy Term'), 'taxonomy_term'),
  'context' => 'ctools_relcontext_from_term_context',
  'settings form' => 'ctools_relcontext_from_term_settings_form',
  // Provides a list of items which are exposed as keywords.
  'convert list' => 'relcontext_from_term_convert_list',   // You need something like this to 
  // Convert keywords into data.
  'convert' => 'relcontext_from_term_convert',
);

/**
 * Return a new context based on an existing context.
 */
function ctools_relcontext_from_term_context($context = NULL, $conf) {

  //break it into a smaller chunk
  $data = $context->data;

  //Loop through the data to get the taxonomy id's
  foreach($data->field_MY_MULTI_TERM_REF_FIELD['und'] as $holder) {
     foreach($holder as $tid) {
       $tids .= '+'.$tid;
     }
  }

  $tids = substr($tids,1);

  // If unset it wants a generic, unfilled context, which is just NULL.
  if (empty($context->data)) {
    return ctools_context_create_empty('multi_term', NULL);
  }


  // NOT SURE HOW TO PROPERLY ADD THE DATA 
  $context->data->multi_term = $tids;
  // ALSO NOT SURE HOW TO BUILD THE DATA TO POPULATE KEYWORD TOKENS

  // You should do error-checking here.

  // Create the new context from some element of the parent context.
  // In this case, we'll pass in the whole context so it can be used to
  // create the relcontext.



  return ctools_context_create('multi_term', $context);
}

/**
 * Settings form for the relationship.
 */
function ctools_relcontext_from_term_settings_form($conf) {
  // We won't configure it in this case.
  return array();
}

// COPY FROM SIMPLE CONTEXT EXAMPLE 
function relcontext_from_term_convert_list() {
  // NEED TO CREATE THE ITEM 1... BEFORE 
  return array(
    'item1' => t('Item1'),
    'item2' => t('Item2'),
    'description' => t('Description'),
  );
}

// COPY FROM SIMPLE CONTEXT EXAMPLE 
function relcontext_from_term_convert($context, $type) {
  switch ($type) {
    case 'item1':
      return $context->data->item1;
    case 'item2':
      return $context->data->item2;
    case 'description':
      return $context->data->description;
  }
}
```

Comment: _there is only the main parent keyword "Keyword: %relcontext_2"_

This usually means the context is in some way broken, and not returning data that Ctools understands how to use. Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi Letharion. Thank you very much for looking at this. Here is a modification  of the sample relationship plugin. I should have put it in before

Comment: Also when I just dropped in the plugin examples provided without modification they only returned the parent keyword. Maybe I am totally misunderstanding how this works ?